# Reactive UI 6: How can I achieve same functionality of version 4 in version 6

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, system.reactive, reactiveui

I have this code from old examples (Reactive UI 4):

```
StartAsyncCommand = new ReactiveCommand();
        StartAsyncCommand.RegisterAsyncAction(_ =>
        {
            Progress = 0;
            var exe = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x =>
                            {
                                Thread.Sleep(100);
                                return x;
                            }).ToObservable();
            exe.Subscribe(x =>Progress += 10);
        });
```

It works fine, UI does not block and button is disable until Progress gets 100%.

When I migrate to version 6, I tried many ways to achieve same functionality without success.

These are my attempts:

1) Using `CreateAsyncObservable`

```
GenerateCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncObservable(canGenerate, x => DoSomething());

public IObservable<Unit> DoSomething()
    {
        var exe = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(
            x =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                return x;
            }).ToObservable().ObserveOnDispatcher().SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default);
        exe.Subscribe(x =>
                Progress += 10
            );
        return Observable.Return(new Unit());
    }
```

It works but button does not disable.

2) With `CreateAsyncTask`

```
GenerateCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(canGenerate, x => DoSomething());

public async Task<Unit> DoSomething()
    {
        var exe = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(
            x =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                return x;
            }).ToObservable().ObserveOnDispatcher().SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default);
                    await exe;
        exe.Subscribe(x =>
                                Progress+=10

            );
        return new Unit();
    }
```

It works but button only disable until await ends.

3) Based on [ReactiveUI 6 Async Command Not Running on Background Thread in WPF app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223340/reactiveui-6-async-command-not-running-on-background-thread-in-wpf-app)

```
GenerateCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(canGenerate, x => DoSomething());

public async Task<Unit> DoSomething()
{
        var execTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var exe = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(
                            x =>
                            {
                                Thread.Sleep(200);
                                return x;
                            }).ToObservable();
            exe.Subscribe(x =>
                    Progress += 10
                );
            return new Unit();
        });

        return execTask.Result; 
 }
```

This throws an exception.

**UPDATE**

4) `Subscribe` command:

```
GenerateCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncObservable(canGenerate, x => DoSomething());
GenerateCommand.ObserveOnDispatcher().SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default)
    .Subscribe(x => Progress += 10);

    public IObservable<int> DoSomething()
    {
        return = Observable.Range(0, 10).Select(
            x =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                return x;
            });
    }
```

Same result...

How could I achieve same functionality with version 6?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you doing `Enumerable.Range(...).ToObservable` instead of `Observable.Range(...)`? You should always avoid going from `Enumerable` to `Observable` where possible.

Comment: Why also are you subscribing to an observable inside a task? It seems like you don't understand how to use Rx properly.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but the question is how achieve same functionality... As I said I tried several codes... I updated question with other code that I also tried... I hope you could help me with an example!

Comment: I wasn't answering the question - I was merely commenting on your code. My feeling is that your troubles stem from the way you are mixing TPL, Rx & Linq (Enumerables).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very odd way to do what you're trying to do. How about this instead:

```
StartAsyncCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncObservable(_ => 
    Observable.Timer(DateTimeOffset.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .Take(10)
        .Scan(0, (acc,x) => acc + 10));

StartAsyncCommand.ToProperty(this, x => x.Progress, out progress);
```